# Cauchy identity, with sum restricted over partitions with first part $\leq n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, schur-functions

The [Cauchy Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial#The_Cauchy_identity) 
$$ \sum_{\nu}s_{\nu}(x)s_{\nu}(y) = \prod_{j,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-x_{j}y_{k}} $$
expresses the sum over all integer partitions of the product of pairs of [Schur polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) as the double product in the right hand side above. Since Schur polynomials verify
$$ s_{\nu}(x_{1},...,x_{n})=0 $$
if $l(\nu)>n$, specializing all but $n$ variables from each set in the Cauchy identity to zero we obtain
$$ \sum_{l(\nu)\leq n}s_{\nu}(x_{1},...,x_{n})s_{\nu}(y_{1},...,y_{n}) = \prod_{j,k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1-x_{j}y_{k}}. $$
Note that the sum is now restricted to partitions of length not greater than $n$.

My question is the following: is there a simple way to express the sum
$$ \sum_{\nu_{1}\leq n}s_{\nu}(x)s_{\nu}(y), $$
where the sum is now restricted to partitions with first part less than or equal to $n$? (possibly specializing variables, as above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum (in any number of variables) is equal to the determinant
$$\det(B_{j-i})_{1\le i,j\le n},$$
where
$$B_i=\sum_{l=0}^\infty e_{l+i}(x)e_l(y),$$
and $e_l$ is the elementary symmetric function, with $e_l=0$ for $l<0$.
This follows by applying the involution $\omega$ in $x$ and $y$ to Theorem 16 of my paper [*Symmetric functions and P-recursiveness*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659090060A), Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A 53 (1990), 257–285. The theorem follows fairly easily from the Cauchy-Binet formula and the Jacobi-Trudi formula.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually wondering if there is also a simpler product expression for this determinant. I know there is one for the determinant in the aforementioned Theorem 16 (namely $\prod_{j,k=1}^{n}(1-x_{j}y_{k})^{-1}$, the one in the question); this is Baxter's identity. There is also such an expression for the determinant resulting from applying the involution $\omega$ in only one of the sets of variables $x$ or $y$ (namely $\prod_{j,k=1}^{n}(1+x_{j}y_{k})$. Do we have an analogue of Baxter's identity for the determinant appearing in your answer?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple product expression. You can check it by just computing the sum for small values of $n$ and small numbers of variables and seeing if it factors.

Comment: @IraGessel  In  another case, if we put condition $λ_1<N$ for $ λ=(λ_1,..,λ_l)$ we arrive to another expression at the $h=1$ (unlike the  $-κ^2 \log [1−h^2]$ that divergent in that point), and principally we can make expansion around $h=1$ .  ($N$ and $N_f$ both tend to ∞ with $κ=N_f/N$ fixed.) First terms appears in another topic https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406707/how-to-calculate-toeplitz-type-determinant-expansion