# How to calculate Toeplitz-type determinant expansion?

Tags: co.combinatorics, determinants, toeplitz-operators

We want to calculate next sum in different point in limit of large $N, N_f$.
Initial expression is expansion around $h=0$ by definition. And the answer is  known . This is ($N_f/N= \kappa$)
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N^2} Z =  \kappa^2 \log \frac{1}{1- h^2} \ .
$$
We start from
$$ Z=  \sum_{r=0}^{N N_f} \ h^{2 l}  \sum_{\lambda \vdash r }s_{\lambda}(1^{N_f})s_{\lambda}(1^{N_f}) =   \prod_{n=1}^{N}  \sum_{l_n=0}^{N_f} \  \ e_{l_n} (H) \det_{1\le i,j\le N}  e_{l_i-i+j} (H)= 
$$
where $s_{\sigma}(1^{N_f})$ is Schur function and  $\sigma \vdash r$ run over partition(with restriction $λ_1\leq N$ for $λ=(λ_1,..,λ_l)$), or alternatively we are using $e_{l_n} (H)$ - elementary symmetric polynomials, where $H=\left(\underbrace{h,\ldots,h}_{N_f \text{ entries}}\right)$.
(See Ira Gessel comments [Cauchy identity, with sum restricted over partitions with first part $\leq n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270204/cauchy-identity-with-sum-restricted-over-partitions-with-first-part-leq-n) ).
We need to reexpand this around $h=1$.

Lets do it:
$$
= \prod_{n=1}^{N}     \sum_{l_n=0}^{N_f} \ h^{2 l_n} \
 \binom{N_f}{l_n}  \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \binom{N_f}{l_i-i+j}   =|h^{2 l_n} =1+2 l_n \log h + \cdots  |
$$
$$
= \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j} + \log h \sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} (N_f+ k-j) \binom{N_f^2}{N_f -i+j} +
$$
$$
{} + (\log h)^2 \left \{ \sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} \frac{(N_f+ k-j)(N_f^2+(1-N_f)(k-j))}{2 N_f -1} \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j} \right. +
$$
$$
\left. +\sum_{k, l=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} (N_f+ k-j)  (N_f+ l-j)  \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j} \right \} + 
$$
$$
{} + (\log h)^3\left \{\sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N}\!\!\!\! \frac{ (N_f+k-j)^2 \left(N_f(N_f+1)+ (2- N_f)(k-j)\right)}{3(2 N_f-1)} \!\!\binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j}+ \cdots \right \}+ O( (\log h)^4) .
$$
Using
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{N_f} \ \binom{N_f}{l} \binom{N_f}{l- i+j} = \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i+ j} 
$$
we came to
$$
  \det_{1\le i, j \le N} \ \binom{2 N_f}{N_f-i +j} = s_{N^{N_f}} \left(1^{2N_f}\right)= \det_{1\le i,j \le N} e_{N_f -i+j} \left(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{2N_f \text{ entries}}\right) =
$$
$$
 =\frac{ G[N+ 2 N_f+1] G[N+1] G[N_f+1]^2 }
{ G[2 N_f+1] G[N+ N_f+1]^2 }\ = Z_0  \ .
$$
(See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681139/determinant-of-a-matrix-with-binomial-coefficient-entries?rq=1).
First correction is simple
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} (N_f+ k-j) \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j}  = N_f N \, Z_0
$$
because of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N  \det_{1\le i,j\le N}  ( k-j) \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j} = \epsilon^{j_1 .. j_N} [(1- j_1)+\cdots +(N- j_N)]
$$
$$
\times\binom{N_f^2}{N_f-1+j_1} \cdots \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-N+j_N}   = 0 \ .
$$
But with next terms we get in trouble (looking at $- 2k\cdot j$ terms)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \det_{1\le i,j\le N} ( k-j)^2 \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-i+j} = \epsilon^{j_1 \cdots j_N} \left \{ [(1+ j_1^2)+ \cdots +(N^2+ j_N^2)]  + \right.
$$
$$
\left. 
{} - 2( j_1+ 2 j_2+ \cdots+  N j_N) \right  \} \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-1+j_1} \cdots \binom{N_f^2}{N_f-N+j_N}=
2 \frac{N(N+1)(2 N+1)}{6} Z_0 + \text{???}
$$
How  to take determinants of this type?

Finally we have first terms of that expansion:
$$
Z= Z_0(1+ N N_f \log h +...)
$$
It is very interesting to obtain all terms.

Comment: Please explain what are $N_f$, $h$, $l_i$ etc.

Comment: $N_f, l_i$ is integer. $h$ is Real.

Comment: Please provide some background as well. Also, why don't you want just collapse the inner sum via binomial theorem: $$\sum_{l_n=0}^{N_f} \ h^{2 l_n} \
 \binom{N_f}{l_n} = (1+h^2)^{N_f}$$ ?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev How we use this formula, summation includes another $l_n$ in determinant. By the way, we start with $(1+h^2)^{N_f}$, why turn back ?

Comment: That's because the question was badly formulated - it was unclear where you started and what's the goal. It's getting better, but still not crystal clear. Also, I cannot parse your formulas w.r.t. $l_i$ - they are defined inside the parentheses, but then all of a sudden are used outside them.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev ok. Now I reformulated the question. What would you say ?

Comment: Version 20 of this question.