# How to re-expand the sum of Schur function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, partitions, schur-functions

Consider next  sum
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{PF_spindef}
Z  =  \sum_{r=0}^{N N_f} h^{2r} \ Q(r)   .
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{equation}
Q(r) \ = \  \sum_{\sigma \vdash r} s_{\sigma}(1^{N_f}) \
s_{\sigma}(1^{N_f}) \ .
\label{QSUN_def}
\end{equation}
where $s_{\sigma}(1^{N_f})$ is Schur function and  $\sigma \vdash r$ run over partition.

Expansion around $h=0$ in the Veneziano  limit    $N \to \infty$ (where $\frac{N_f}{N }= \kappa $) explicitly gives
$$
Z= 1 + h^2 N^2 \kappa^2  + \frac{h^4}{2} N^2 \kappa^2( N^2 \kappa^2 + 1) + \frac{h^6 }{6} N^2 \kappa^2 (N^2 \kappa^2 +1)(N^2 \kappa^2 +2) + ... = e^{ N^2 \kappa^2 \log \frac{1}{1- h^2} } 
$$
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N^2} Z =  \kappa^2 \log \frac{1}{1- h^2} 
$$

How to re-expand initial $Z$ (in terms of Schur functions) around $h=1$  and takes  the same Veneziano limit ?

Comment: $N_f$ is just some number here? The notation is confusing to me...

Comment: Yes $N, N_f$ is some integer.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Just a piece of advice: You will get better help here if you try to formulate your questions without unnecessary notation (like calling a number $N_f$ instead of just $n$) and physics lingo (Veneziano limit).

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case of the generating function for Schur polynomials
$$\sum_{\lambda}s_\lambda(x_1,\dots,x_m)s_\lambda(y_1,\dots,y_n)=\prod_{i=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^n\frac 1{1-x_iy_j}.$$
Take $x_1=\dots=x_m=x$ and $y_1=\dots=y_n=1$, gives
$$\sum_{\lambda} x^{|\lambda|}s_\lambda(1^m)s_\lambda(1^n)=\frac 1{(1-x)^{mn}}.$$
It seems you take $m=n=N\kappa=N_f$ and $x=h^2$. You have indeed
$$\frac 1{N^2}\log \sum_{\lambda}s_\lambda(1^{N_f})^2 h^{2|\lambda|}=\frac 1{N^2}\log \frac 1{(1-h^2)^{N^2\kappa^2}}=\kappa^2\log \frac 1{1-h^2}.$$

Note that $s_\lambda(1^n)$ are the dimensions of the irreducible representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$, so you can probably also give a representation-theoretic proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However we interesting in another  case,   if we put condition  $\lambda_1<N$ for $\lambda=(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_l)$ we arrive to another expression at the $h=1$ (unlike the - $\kappa^2 \log [1-h^2]$  that diverges in that point), and principally we can  make expansion around $h=1$ . First terms appears in another topic https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406707/how-is-to-calculate-toeplitz-type-determinant-expansion .

Comment: So you want to put a bound $\lambda_1\leq N$ on the terms and then look at the asymptotics when $N$ and $N_f$ both tend to $\infty$ with $\kappa=N_f/N$ fixed?

Comment: Yes! This is the case.